# How to Stream logs from Azure Web Apps without signing into the Azure portal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, logging, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have my .Net apps hosted in Azure Web Apps. Is there any way that I can stream/view the application/server log traces directly using without signing into the portal.
The reason why I need this is because, My contains the fellow developers who will not be having access to the Azure portal.

Please help if any solution for this. Thanks in Advance.

I have tried enabling the log streaming inside the Azure portal.But that doesn't meet my requirement.
Also tried storing the logs to the Azure storage account. But cannot find any opensource tools to fetch and read the logs. And feels this as a time consuming solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mohit's recommendations are great and probably the best advice, however:

I have a suggestion which does not fulfil the requirement of not having a role in Azure, but may offer such an advantage that it could be worth it. Using the Azure CLI you can stream out the logs:

`az webapp log tail --name appname --resource-group myResourceGroup`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#streamlogs

You may be able to setup a role with sufficient constraints that all the developer can do is read the diagnostic logs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/roles-permissions-security

Also if you are not familiar with it, I'd suggest looking at Azure Application Insights, it does not have the super low level logs, but likely sufficient for diagnosing issues that a developer would typically run into. And has many advanced features that make it far easier to diagnose things than looking at log files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to achieve that is to use storage account and container for application and diagnostic logging.

To enable diagnostics for your Azure web app, you can do the following:

- Log in to your account at https://portal.azure.com/.
- Go to your Azure Web App and select Settings > Diagnostics logs.
- For Application Logging (Blob), click On and set the parameters.

  - Set the Level for the logging.
  - For Storage Settings, click > and select the Storage Account and Container.

This is the Storage Account and Container that Azure will use to store logs for the Web App. Make note of this information because you will need it to set up a log collection job in USM Anywhere. You can click + Storage Account to create a new storage account or container, or select an existing one.

- For Web server logging, select Storage.
- Click Storage Settings and select the same storage account and container that you set for the application logging.

Once done then you can share the Azure storage container using SAS shared access signature.

SAS will having a URI which will have the predefined access on the container, By this way you will be able to see logs without accessing Azure portal.

```
A shared access signature (SAS) is a URI that allows you to specify the time span and permissions allowed for access to a storage resource such as a blob or container. The time span and permissions can be derived from a stored access policy or specified in the URI. We’ll cover both of these in detail later.
```

You can refer below docs for reference.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/10/12/easily-create-a-sas-to-download-a-file-from-azure-storage-using-azure-storage-explorer/

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-9-shared-access-signatures/

https://www.alienvault.com/documentation/usm-anywhere/deployment-guide/azure/azure-enable-diagnostics.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: Agreed this is best if not wanting an Azure role as Leo suggested. +1 from me.